# c - using nl80211 without libnl or libnl-genl?

Tags: linux, network-programming, wifi

I'm hoping to just use the header in the kernel, `linux/nl80211.h` to get the channel my network device is on.  I'm on a very restricted system where building has to happen with a minimum number of extra packages.  It feels strange that `SIOCGIWFREQ` would be so easy to get, but I'd need a library to just get a frequency via nl80211.

Are there any examples of how to use the nl80211 interface directly in Linux?  I'm just hoping to get  `NL80211_FREQUENCY_ATTR_FREQ`

Comment: Just scan the sources, maybe you'll find some examples there. Or am I not understanding your question?

Comment: This sounds silly, but, I was just about to reply "All the examples I could find were using libnl."  I never thought to read the libnl sources.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a lot of struggling, I found out!  It's actually easier to use netlink *without* libnl, as long as you're not doing anything complicated.

I wrote up an example here that prints all your wireless devices, what networks and channels they're connected to: https://github.com/cnlohr/netlink_without_libnl/blob/master/without_libnl.c